VS 2022 ML.NET Tutorial - Training Never Stops
My first attempt at experimenting with ML. I am attempting to start simple where ML will tell me how much has been refunded in 3 different contexts.
The "Scenario" i have selected is "Question Answering"

and my "Environment" is "Local (GPU)" with a CUDA compliant GPU

I think i have created the file with the correct column headings and calculated the AnswerIndex correctly.
Please see screenshot below.

I have an Intel i7-10700F 2.90Ghz processor, with 32gb of RAM and a NVIDIA Ge|Force GTX 1080 with latest drivers.
When the "training" is in progress i never see GPU % go above 4% for Visual Studio
I have also made sure i have the latest version of the VS extension installed.
My problem is that the training never finishes, even after hours of training.
Any pointers on what i maybe doing wrong would be appreciated. Or does training take multiple hours?
